# Не работает padding

Tags: html, css

Начал проходить анимацию css, но не смог построить даже кнопки, почему то не работает padding

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="button">Наведи на меня</div>
</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
body{
    position: absolute;
}
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background-color: blue;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px, 50px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

Результат такой(
[image: Результат такой(]

Comment: не `padding: 10px, 50px;` а `padding: 10px 50px;`

Comment: Ой, спасибо, не заметил)